# Wordpress: disable white screen of death, enable standard PHP errors

Tags: wordpress, error-reporting

Is there any way to disable white screen of death (Error that says "Sorry, we are experiencing technical difficulties") and make it show the standard PHP errors? Have been looking for hours for solution:

I have set up the wp-config

```
ini_set('log_errors','On');
ini_set('display_errors','On');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

I have enabled error reporting in php.ini.

Still, it does show error report for some errors and shows the white screen for others, and sometimes (not always) it adds the errors to error log. So, is there any way to stop this "smart" thing of wordpress and make consider the PHP error reporting as a priority?

Thanks

Comment: at such a situation i first check if file i am working is correct.. and then try to echo and die in the file to check flow.

Comment: that's what I am doing, but you must agree this is crazy. It's takes way more time to program this thing

Comment: yes... that's crazy..

Answer (score 0):

may be you should try looking

> .htacces file

Some web hosting providers allow to modify php parameters from .htaccess file like this.

> php_value display_errors 1

Here is php.net documentation for this.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Here are some more directives that you can add to htaccess or domain's httpd.conf

## #hide php errors

php_flag display_startup_errors ON

php_flag display_errors ON

php_flag html_errors ON

php_flag log_errors on

php_flag ignore_repeated_errors off

php_flag ignore_repeated_source off

php_flag report_memleaks on

php_flag track_errors on

php_value docref_root 0

php_value docref_ext 0

php_value error_log /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log

php_value error_reporting 999999999

php_value error_reporting -1

php_value log_errors_max_len 0

Order allow,deny

Deny from all

Satisfy All

Comment: As I've stated - I have setup the php.ini correspondingly. It's not apache problem - it's wordpress that blocks the standard error reporting with their own script

Comment: ok.. I got this wordpress help page related to this.. https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/ hope that helps.